# Why is my computed method running both server and client side?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm making a Universal Application with Nuxt and Vue.js and I noticed that my button was having some weird behaviour, it changed class after the page was loaded, and since it has a transition it became quite annoying.

I set the class of the button with a computed method. So I tried putting a console.log in the computed method, and then I saw that it called both server-side and client-side? How is this possible? Is there anything that I need to do so that the method will only be called server-side?

```
<template>
    <a :href="link" :class="themeClass">
        <slot />
    </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: { 
        link:{
            type:String,
            default: '',
        },
        theme:
        {
            type:String,
            default: 'primary',
            validator: (value) => ['secondary', 'tertiary'].includes(value),
        },
        inverted:{
            type:Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    computed:{
        themeClass: function()
        {
            console.log("set style");
            let invertedStyle = this.inverted ? '-inverted' : '';
            return 'butt ' + this.theme + invertedStyle;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.butt{
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.primary{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
}

.primary:hover{
    border: 2px solid $primary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.primary-inverted{
    border: 2px solid $primary-color;
    color: $primary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.primary-inverted:hover{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
}

.secondary{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $secondary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
}

.secondary:hover{
    border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.secondary-inverted{
    border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.secondary-inverted:hover{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $secondary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
}

.tertiary{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $tertiary-color;
    color: $primary-color;
}

.tertiary:hover{
    border: 2px solid $tertiary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.tertiary-inverted{
    border: 2px solid $tertiary-color;
    color: $tertiary-color;
    @include alphaBackground();
}

.tertiary-inverted:hover{
    border: 2px solid $transparant;
    background-color: $tertiary-color;
    color: $primary-color;
}
</style>
```

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/

Comment: But I want it to be rendered server side

Comment: then its not computed? its async data: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from the Nuxt discord

```
computed: {
  something() {
    return !process.client ? 'runs on server' : ''
  }
}
```

Comment: isnt this the same as your example? just that the return value is based on location?